# How to measure execution time in FreeRTOS?

Tags: c, real-time, freertos

I have a version of FreeRTOS which comes with a TraceAlyzer tool and I need to compare how it affects the effectivity of the whole systems (for what time it slows it down). I have 2 simple tasks which run and delay for a short time. I run system twice with Tracealyzer started and without for some number of iterations.

I am aware of vTaskGetRunTimeStats(), but as far as I understand it only measures the run time of one task, not of the entire system. At the moment I am using the PowerShell tool `Measure-Command`, but I would like to use a built-in tool in FreeRTOS.

**How do I measure the execution time for the entire system (all tasks, not just one) in FreeRTOS?**

Comment: https://www.freertos.org/Documentation/FreeRTOS_Reference_Manual_V10.0.0.pdf ? I just google it... you should learn to search yourself

Comment: @Stargateur Well, that's a useless comment. I wouldn't ask a question here if the solution could be found in the manual.

Comment: You'd be surprised. And when asking for a "best" solution you should specify the metric by which you want to measure that.

Comment: In the manual, I found **2.3** `vTaskGetRunTimeStats()` about which it says "FreeRTOS can be configured to collect task run time statistics." Is this appropriate for you?

Comment: @WeatherVane That is also what I found, but I managed to get it running only for one task. My problem is that I would like to get the total system runtime, i.e. for all tasks. At the moment I am measuring the time for the whole system externally through 'Measure-Command', but this seems quite inaccurate. I'll update the question to clarify that.

Comment: Sorry, I fail my link, I forget it was a pdf, search the fonction `xTimerCreate()`, page 259

Comment: I further quote from the manual 2.3 `vTaskGetRunTimeStats()` "Task run time statistics provide information on the amount of processing time **each task** has received." (my emphasis).

Comment: Ah, I see. But it seems this doesn't count delays, interrupts, etc., but only the pure run time. Is there a way to also include all this overhead in the measurement?

Answer (score 1):

vTaskGetRunTimeStats() will provide stats for all tasks, provided you have configured the clock it uses.  This image is an example of the data it provides:
https://freertos.org/rtos-run-time-stats.jpg

If you just want the raw data then use https://freertos.org/uxTaskGetSystemState.html